# When Redirecting output of a command in Tcl to file, file is getting generated in DOS format

Tags: c++, c, tcl

I want to develop a command 'redirect' in Tcl, which takes as an argument command to be executed and redirects output of command to the file provided by the user. I am using below code and it is working well. The only problem with  this code is that the file is getting created in DOS format. How do i get rid of this as the format should be Unix style not DOS?

I tried setting :set binary in VI editor and other workarounds as
vim +"argdo setlocal ff=unix" +wqa 
However, it could not find any reason why is this file getting created in DOS format.

```
Tcl_Channel stdoutChannel = Tcl_GetStdChannel(TCL_STDOUT);

Tcl_Channel stderrChannel = Tcl_GetStdChannel(TCL_STDERR);

if(stdoutChannel) {

  Tcl_Flush(stdoutChannel);

}

if(stderrChannel) {

  Tcl_Flush(stderrChannel);

}

FILE* filePtr = fopen(filename, "wb");

int pfd = fileno(filePtr);

int saved = dup(1);

close(1);

Tcl_Obj* commandResult = Tcl_NewStringObj(command,strlen(command));

dup2(pfd,STDOUT_FILENO);

Tcl_EvalObj(TBXslaveInterp,commandResult);

close(pfd);

fflush(stdout);

// restore it back

dup2(saved, 1);

close(saved);

return TCL_OK;
```

### OUTPUT

```
Command executed : 
redirect myfile {puts "Inside Tcl"}

Viewing File in VI at the bottom shows:

"myfile" [dos] 1L, 12C


 cat myfile 

 Inside Tcl^M
```

Notice ^M is printed when cat operation performed. This is because of the DOS style format in which the file is saved.

Comment: Please have a quick checkup with the articles in the help section and rephrase and format your question. Your question is unreadable, sry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tcl lets you control the line ending conversion for a channel (file handle, socket, etc.) using the `chan configure` command (also called `fconfigure`). In particular, you want to configure the `-translation` option to be either `lf` (for use line-feeds) or `binary` (which sets a few other things as well). Tcl *ignores* the setting in C stdio, as it accesses the OS directly to do I/O, and the line ending translation isn't done at that point.

Put one of these in your script, depending on what exactly you're doing:

```
chan configure stdout -translation lf
```

```
chan configure stdout -translation binary
```

You can also set the channel translation from C:

```c
/* Guess what 'chan configure' is a wrapper around? */
Tcl_SetChannelOption(interp, stdoutChannel, "-translation", "binary");
```